# Change color of specific cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagridView in winform Application. I want to achieve backcolor of cells like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dg.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is  my demo is:

> datagridview1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

in your case :

```
if (data1 == 0 && data2 == "Indirect Expence")
{
  datagridview1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: `DataGridView` is different from `DataGrid` your link points to correct resource but code is for `DataGridView`

Comment: You didnt got my problem. I want to color two cells of the same row green and the other two orange of that same row.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code I used a while back now. This should help you.

```
private void dgvOutstandingReports_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
            {
                int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
                int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;


                if (rowIndex >= 0 && colIndex >= 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow theRow = dgvOutstandingReports.Rows[rowIndex];


                    if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "Daily Report")
                    {
                        theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                    }
                    else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "Monthly Report")
                    {
                        theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                    }
                    else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "SMP Report")
                    {
                        theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Snow;
                    }
                    else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "Weekly Report")
                    {
                        theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                    }
                    else if (theRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "Hourly Report")
                    {
                        theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
```